# Dynamically import module into a python function

Tags: python, import, parameters, module

I have this project structure

```
utilities.py 
/references
    module1.py
    module2.py
    ...
```

Into the utilities.py file, I would like to have a function with dynamically import with parameters like that :

```
def import(self, file):    
    from references.file import file  
    ...
```

Into the utilities.py file I use

```
import("module1")
```

But it doesn't work, I have the following error

```
from references.file import steps ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'references.file'
```

I need some help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import using string names then try the [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) function.

You could have a function that worked something like:

```
def dynamic_import(file):
    importlib.import_module(f'references.{file}')
```

For even more control you could use the [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) builtin, but that's more involved and not really recommended